# Deleting by value from a single linked list

Tags: c++

So I have been trying to filter my list. The list is correctly created and filled, but I got some entries twice from my document. It should be like that. Now I am trying to filter them out and I think I got a pretty good idea of it but its not working properly.

```
Anmeldung* delete_object(Anmeldung* b){

    Anmeldung* tmp = b;
    b = b->next;
    delete(tmp);

    return b;
}


void filter_list(Anmeldung* b){

    Anmeldung* tmp = b;

    while(b!=NULL){
        std::string info = b->Matrikelnummer;

        while(tmp!=NULL){

            if(tmp->Matrikelnummer == info){
                tmp = delete_object(tmp);
            }else
                tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        b = b->next;
        tmp = b;
    }
}
```

So I am trying to iterate through my list and compare every value with the whole list. The value I am searching for is `Matrikelnummer` if two persons got the same Matrikelnummer one gets deleted.

This is my struct Anmeldung. This is provide from my Professor:

```
struct Anmeldung {
  Anmeldung* next;
  std::string   Nachname;             // Name Teilnehmer
  std::string   Vorname;              // Vorname Teilnehmer
  std::string   Email;                // Email Adresse Teilnehmer
  std::string   Matrikelnummer;       // Matrikelnr. Teilnehmer
  std::string   Studienrichtung;      // Studienrichtung Teilnehmer
  std::string   Semester;             // Studiensemester Teilnehmer
  std::string   G1name;               // Name Wunschkandidat fuer Praktikumsgruppe
  std::string   G1vorname;            // Vorname Wunschkandidat
  std::string   Anmerkung;            // Freier Text
};
```

I think the `while`loops are correct and the `delete_object` is wrong but i can't see where or how.
I am not allowed to use the container list or anything like that. I only got the struct. So no double linked list nothing.

Comment: but i reassign `tmp` with my delete_object or? so tmp should have a the value of the following object? No just the one with the same value of `Matrikelnummer`

Comment: It's unfortunate that the German word for "registration" sounds like the English phrase "animal dung"...

Answer (score 0):

When you call `delete_object()` you do not delete the object being passed, you delete the *next* entry in your linked list. So your `if()` statement is finding the correct node to delete, but then you proceed to delete the node *after* it instead. You should fix that (but do keep the general idea of returning the node after the one you deleted).

Also your logic of the unconditional `tmp = tmp->next` would lead you to *skip* the node being returned by `delete_object()` if called. You should probably put that statement inside an `else` clause instead, because once you fix `delete_object()` it will return the next node you want to continue with for you as well.

Comment: Alright I understand! So in my `delete_object()` i should write `tmp = b` and `b = b->next`? But that still doesn't work.. I am losing the pointer somewhere. I got the exit code 11. I updated my code on top.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet looking into details but in `filter_list` you have `Anmeldung* tmp = b;`, meaning that `if(tmp->Matrikelnummer == info){` is always true.

Comment: No its not? I am iterating with `tmp = tmp->next;` through my list right?

Comment: When your function being called, `if(tmp->Matrikelnummer == info){` would be processed before `tmp = tmp->next`, right? @HenningWilmer

Comment: Oh yes you are right. I didn't even realize that because I am always getting exit code 11..